# addition between two jtextfield

Tags: java, parsing, jtextfield

I have a problem with the following:

I want to add the `java.lang.String` values of two `JTextfields` together.

How can I convert the data in such a manner that this is possible?

Comment: looking in the API is always a good first step http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Addition :

   `int result = Integer.valueOf(jTextField1.getText()) + Integer.valueOf(jtextField2.getText());`
2. Multiplication :

   `int result = Integer.valueOf(jtextField1.getText()) * Integer.valueOf(jtextField.getText());`

Note : Use `Double.valueOf()` if the values are floating point literals.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get values of both jtextfield.
2. Use Integer.parseInt or Double.parseDouble depending on your data type .
3. Now you will have those value in int/double. you can use any maths operator on them.

   - , *